# How to integrate Kibana with nagios?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nagios, elasticsearch-5, amazon-elasticsearch

We use ELK for log management and nagios for centralized monitoring.
I want to setup pattern match alerts in kibana and notify via nagios.
Can you please let me know if this is feasible.

Comment: This site is more about programming then recommendation how integrate ELK with Nagios. But take a look https://github.com/elasticfence/nagios_es_watcher, you can use similar script to query Elasticsearch.